# Как добавить все MonoBehaviours на сцене в List?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я недавно читал статью [10 000 ВЫЗОВОВ UPDATE()](http://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/). Автор использует свой `UpdateManager`. Этот менеджер имеет свой метод `Update`, который вызывает все методы
`Update` во всех других компонентах `MonoBehaviours` всех объектов. Это работает быстрее, нежели вызов `Update` в каждом `MonoBehaviour`  отдельно..
Его менеджер выглядит так:

```
private ManagedUpdateBehavior[] list;

private void Start() {
    list = GetComponents<ManagedUpdateBehavior>();
}

private void Update() {
    var count = list.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // UpdateMe
        list[i].UpdateMe();
    }
}
```

И каждый объект теперь должен содержать скрипт с кодом:

```
public class ManagedUpdateBehavior : MonoBehaviour {
    // some variables

    public void UpdateMe() {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

Если объектов, использующих этот компонент не много, то легко их найти. А если их 100? 1000? 10000?

Как найти все объекты на сцене и добавить им всем `ManagedUpdateBehaviors`. Должен ли я использовать какой-либо рекурсивный метод обхода при старте? Ведь каждый объект может содержать другой объект со скриптом, тот, в свою очередь другой объект. Неограниченная вложенность.
Также объекты динамически инстанциируются и удаляются со сцены, то нужно как-то их динамически добавлять в список тоже. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы найти все объекты с типом `ManagedUpdateBehavior` достаточно воспользоваться методом [Object.FindObjectsOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html).  например:

```
private static List<ManagedUpdateBehavior> list;

private void Start () 
{
    list = Object.FindObjectsOfType<ManagedUpdateBehavior>().ToList();      
}
```

Но правда он не найдет неактивные объекты. А с учетом того, что

> Также объекты динамически инстанциируются и удаляются со сцены

то нет необходимости каждый раз искать что-то и добавлять им компонент. Достаточно модифицировать `ManagedUpdateBehavior` таким образом, чтобы при появлении он сам себя заносил в список некоего подписчика, 
назовем его `UpdateSubscriber`, а при удалени объекта со сцены, он удалял бы себя из списка.

Итак, модифицированный `ManagedUpdateBehavior`, который нужно добавить всем объектам, чьи характеристики будем обновлять (то есть вызывать *UpdateMe*) из общего менеджера будет таким:

```
public class ManagedUpdateBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    UpdateSubscriber updateSUBSCR;

    // Добавляем себя в список
    void Start()
    {
        updateSUBSCR = GameObject.Find("UpdateSUBSCR").GetComponent<UpdateSubscriber>();
        updateSUBSCR.addManagedUpdateBehavior(this);
    }

    // Удаляем себя из списка
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        updateSUBSCR.removeManagedUpdateBehavior(this);
    }

    public void UpdateMe()
    {
        // some logic
        Debug.Log("Update from: " + gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Далее на сцене создаем объект (наш подписчик),  с именем **UpdateSUBSCR** и прикрепляем к нему скрипт:

```
public class UpdateSubscriber : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<ManagedUpdateBehavior> managedUpdateBehavior = new List<ManagedUpdateBehavior>();

    public void addManagedUpdateBehavior(ManagedUpdateBehavior managedUB)
    {
        managedUpdateBehavior.Add(managedUB);
    }

    public void removeManagedUpdateBehavior(ManagedUpdateBehavior managedUB)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < managedUpdateBehavior.Count; i++)
        {
            if (managedUpdateBehavior[i] == managedUB)
            {
                managedUpdateBehavior.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public void updateAll()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < managedUpdateBehavior.Count; i++)
        {
            managedUpdateBehavior[i].UpdateMe();
        }
    }

    /*
    public List<ManagedUpdateBehavior> getManagedUpdateBehaviorinstance
    {
        get
        {
            return managedUpdateBehavior;
        }
    }*/
}
```

А также добавить скрипт ниже, который будет отдельно вызывать `Update` у это самого менеджера, который в свою очередь будет вызывать все методы `UpdateMe` у объектов в списке

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    UpdateSubscriber updateSUBSCR;

    void Start()
    {
        updateSUBSCR = GameObject.Find("UpdateSUBSCR").GetComponent<UpdateSubscriber>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        updateSUBSCR.updateAll();
    }
}
```

<sub>Ответ переведен и чуть дополнен с https://stackoverflow.com/a/38541620/6104996</sub>